# Symfony2 Dependency Injection

Tags: symfony, propel

I would like to do the following:

Inside a bundle through dependency injection add propel connection.
So every bundle can have a connection that on load will be merged all together.

Is this possible?

I have achieved this via

```
- { resource: @XXXX/Resources/config/databases.yml }
- { resource: @XXXXX/Resources/config/databases.yml }
```

but would like to do it via Dependency Injection as it will be best practice in my opinion.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully clear to me. I only understood the part with loading additional configuration files in your bundles.

Bundle configurations can be loaded automatically with DIC extensions. That's what happens with the `Resources/config/services.xml` file.

Read more on [Loading External Configuration Resources](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#loading-external-configuration-resources).